# Storing Row numbers of duplicate records (based on 2 or more columns) to an array

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a record set comprising a lastName, firstName, Address, and PolicyID (and a bunch of other columns).

I want to see if there are more than one "Tim Jones" not just more than one Tim and/or more than one person with the last name of Jones. I do not want to create additional columns in the worksheet, nor do I want to use conditional formatting or have the user use a formula in the formula bar. The goal is for this to be hands-off for the user, save for executing a macro.

I am trying to run a loop that stores the row numbers of records where the first+last name appear elsewhere in the record-set. See table:

```
 Legend: M = Matches, X = does not match

    | First | Last | Address | PolicyID | Description                                      |
    |-------|------|---------|-----------|-------------------------------------------------|
    | M     | M    | M       | M         | Duplicate Row, Delete duplicates                |
    | M     | M    | M       | X         | Same person, multiple Policies, mark rows yellow|
    | M     | M    | X       | M         | Same person, multiple addresses, mark rows blue |
    | M     | M    | X       | X         | Not necessarily the same person, mark grey      |
```

I figured running additional checks against the smaller subset of records where the first and last name matched would help this run more efficiently.

The description column details what I am looking to do with the data initial as far as formatting. Eventually I would move/copy/delete rows depending on which criteria they met.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an easier way you could do this without the use of VBA.  Place this formula in the Description column for the 3rd line in Excel (e.g. cell E3) and then copy it down.  If you still need rows to change color, you could set up conditional formatting based on the Description results.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,B:B,B3,C:C,C3,D:D,D3)>1,"Duplicate Row",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,B:B,B3,C:C,C3)>1,"Same person, multiple Policies",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,B:B,B3,D:D,D3)>1,"Same person, multiple addresses",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,B:B,B3)>1,"Not necessarily the same person",""))))`